# how to write a c function which creates an empty queue?

Tags: c, queue, linked-list

I am new to C. I have no idea about how to write a C function which creates an empty queue and return a void pointer.

```
void* queue_open(void)
```

I also want to know how to write a C function which puts an element at end of a queue.

```
void queue_put(void *p, void *elementp)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this homework? What does your reference material say about implementing linked lists?

Comment: Yes, it is my homework. It's basically as me to create a shopping list to take entries from the keyboard. Each entry is composed of an item to purchase (string) and the number of items to purchase (int). After all items have been entered, print out the shopping list, remove all entries from the queue, close the queue. The home work as us to use modular programming, such as function creates an empty queue. I have main function done using functions like queue_open and queue_put. Now, I don't know how to write those functions.

Comment: What did you learn in class? Do you have reference material? Textbooks? Surely you can find linked list code on the web.

Comment: I am taking a lab based programming course, without textbooks. Every week, there is an assignment(coding subject). I have to learn by myself.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to find out in more detail exactly what you want to do (which will go a long way in solving the current question). If you are not familiar with TDD (test driven development) read up on some of that and start writing some tests (before implementing the actual functions). The queue_open function should probably return NULL, test for that. Can the function fail for some reason (and will it then return NULL)? After calling queue_open and queue_put the length of the queue should be 1. Test for that, etc

Comment: Not sure about TDD. Surely you need to learn the basics before that!

Answer (score 2):

If you are coming from an object oriented background (as your method signatures seem to indicate).

Object oriented idea -> good way to do it in C

Object creation -> malloc a struct, then pass it into an initialization function

```
struct queue* q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
queue_initialize(q);
```

if you want, you can wrap this in a function, like so

```
struct queue* queue_construct() {
  struct queue* q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  queue_initialize(q);
  return q;
}
```

Note that these pointer shouldn't point to void*, let C do at least some of the type checking for you.

Implement a method -> create a function that takes a struct pointer to the "almost this" struct.

```
struct user* user = ... whatever we do here ...;
queue_add(q, (void*)user);
```

As far as how to actually implement a queue, I suggest a good data structures or algorithms book, as there are many ways to go about it; and, the specific techniques you choose will have different impacts on performance and reliability.  There's no one best way, it depends heavily on how the queue is to be used, and which aspects of performance are more important.

The book I recommend is [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844).  This book is overkill for most situations, with very detailed listings of nearly every major data structure you are likely to encounter in the first few years of programming.  As such, it makes a great reference, despite its attempt at a language neutral approach, which now looks odd when compared to common programming languages.

Once you understand what is going on, you can do it in nearly any language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what a queue element should look like, what a queue is, and what it means for a queue to be empty. If you know those things, writing `queue_open` and `queue_put` should be pretty easy. I'd suggest that you start by defining a structure that represents your queue element.

Comment: here is my structure:                                                            
typedef struct item {
  int num;
  char name[MAXSTR];
} Item;

Comment: That *could* be an element in your queue, but what makes it a queue? What's the relationship between two consecutive elements in a queue, and how do you plan to create that relationship? Here's a hint: two basic structures that can implement a queue are linked list and array.

Comment: Right. If you're using a linked list, then each item needs a next pointer, and a pointer to a queue is just a pointer to the first element. If you use an array, you don't need the next pointer, but you have to pre-allocate the array of items, and you need a way to remember which item is the first one and how many items are currently in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about queues here:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29)

While you could easily copy and paste the sample code from the link above and with little modification solve your homework problem, you are not going to learn a lot by doing that.

After understanding a queue conceptually, I recommend you try to implement it yourself, then use the sample code from the link above as a reference when you get stuck.

The best thing you could do is pair up with another student in your class who is smarter than you. Then pair program ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming ) with him/her to solve the problem. You'll become a better programmer.